# How can i run an autoit script on Windows server 2016 without the remote desktop turned on?

Tags: windows, autoit

I have a script that i want to run on a windows vserver (windows server 2016)
but when i close the remote desktop the script doesn´t continue. Is there any way that i can make this script run on that server? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping AutoIt-controlled remote desktop session "alive"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528412/keeping-autoit-controlled-remote-desktop-session-alive)

Answer (score 0):

From your question i assume it is a task that has to run in the background and you do not want to start/stop it frequently, you could register your script application as a service using sc.exe. Take a look at the [syntax here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create).

Note:
You will need administrator privileges for register, so you need to be admin to start and stop a service or an admin have to grant these permissions if it is possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script by Task Scheduler. Create new task and mark these options: "Run whether user is logged on or not", "Do not store password", "Run with highest privileges".

Also you can try to use Psexec tool from [PsTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools) package for remote start.